# Tabs to other review tasks

Tags: feature-request, review, tabs

When I am reviewing, I normally start with close votes, then review low quality posts, and then suggested edits. What bugs me is when I have to go to the top of the page to the main review page to go to the next task. I propose putting tabs on all review pages as shown below so one can switch between them when one is finished with one task.

[image]

The current tab will be highlighted or something to show which tab one is currently on. I'm open to design modifications, but I just want some tabs somewhere to the other tasks.